# StringTemplate for runtime code gen?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, code-generation, stringtemplate

I am working on a project that generates code at runtime based on meta-model. I've used vb.net xml literals for this, but today I ran across [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) project. Has anybody successfully used this library in C# project.

Comment: Yep. I used it to generate text files. Very easy to use.

Comment: Did you use .net2.0 binary distribution? I tried source code one but it won't compile.

Comment: Is your output XML, or plain text?

Comment: plain text, outputs code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StringTemplate is probably the most awesome and well-designed templating engine in existence today. It's definitely a good pick regardless of the language/platform you use.

On the other hand, ther's also T4, which is "more standard" (comes with VS, reusable, a lot of .NET devs know it already), and in VS2010 it comes with "precompiled templates", where your template is converted to raw C# code at design time, which is compiled as part of your project - which is fast, and has no runtime dependencies.